# <a> not stretching to fill <li>

Tags: html, css

`<a>` not stretching to fill `<li>`.
http://www.bungle.ca - Horizontal nav bar on the top.

This has dozens of questions searchable;

- Element has missing tags: My code validates.
- Element is floated left: None of mine are floated.
- Elements have padding: None of mine are padded.
- Inline element has width set: Mine do not.

Not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: Welcome to [SO], please read the [faq] if you haven't already. It also looks as though you need some [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set a height on the `<li>`, but didn't set one on the `<a>`, so you're expecting the `<a>` to magically fill the `<li>`? Not going to work. Specify a height on the `<a>` instead of the `<li>` and you should be good.

Comment: Unbelievably quick, worked like a charm.  Thanks, can't check mark yet.